# Roboto is the new Droid

Tags: feature-request, design

As [this article explains](http://www.theverge.com/2011/12/7/2585779/android-history), Android's visual identity has moved from the Droid Sans font to the Roboto font as of Android 4.0. However, the licensing for the font is unclear (to me) and [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roboto) doesn't seem to shine light on this matter.

Can this site use Roboto in place of Droid Sans? Should it?

Comment: Android is customizable. Perhaps useres here should be able to choose which font they see.

Comment: @gary The mobile site could potentially take advantage of the user agent and choose the matching font by default.

Comment: @MatthewRead that would be cool (even if it's subtle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added "Roboto" to the font stack for the site(both main and Meta).

For now I'm not using it as a web font like I did with Droid Sans, since I'm not too clear on the re-distribution licensing.

Roboto should show up on handheld after the next production build. Meanwhile if you want to see it on your desktop, you can [download](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto) the font manually.

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/license/roboto _seems_ to suggest it would be fine

Comment: I have the font installed on my PC (Windows XP) but unfortunately it is not so beautiful to see on desktop as it is on Android devices.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but could you revisit including Robot as a web font? Personally I think it looks a lot better than Droid Sans. ;)

Comment: @hichris123 we have been using Roboto as a web font though. do you not see it?

Comment: @Jin Now I do, but previously it was rendering as Droid Sans on Windows.